# mp3 and mp4 requests pending in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

I saw, [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479374/multiple-mp4-requests-in-chrome-stuck-in-pending) but there are no answers.
Things work fine on IE11 and Firefox, the problem is observed only in Chrome.

I request videos (mp4 etc.) and audio (mp3) via REST calls in respective tags.

```
<video data-ng-src="{{videoRestURL}}" type="video/mp4"></video>

<audio data-ng-src="{{audioRestURL}}" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

These media requests are served properly for initial requests, but after requesting same video/audio multiple times, the request starts to go into `pending` state.

I also tried to add random Id to the end of URL for each request, but that doesn't help either. (see below image)

[image: requests in chrome]

How can I solve this issue?